Derivation of Noether Current in Condensed Matter Field Theory by Altland and Simons
In Section 1.6 of Condensed Matter Field Theory by Altland and Simons, they prove Noether's theorem. In order to do so, they consider an infinitesimal transformation of the coordinates and the field:
$$
\begin{align}
x_\mu \to x'_\mu =& x_\mu + \left.\frac{\partial x_\mu}{\partial \omega_a}\right|_{\omega = 0} \omega_a(x), \cr \phi^i(x) \to \phi'^i(x') =& \phi^i(x) + \omega_a(x) F^i_a[\phi]\end{align}\tag{1.42}
$$
to linear order in a set of parameter functions $\{\omega_a\}$ characterizing the transformation, where the functionals $\{F^i_a\}$ can depend on the coordinate $x$ and define the incremental change $\phi'(x') - \phi(x)$.
They then compute the change $\Delta S$ in the action to linear order in $\omega_a$ as
$$
\Delta S = \int d^m x'\, \mathcal{L}(\phi'^i(x'), \partial_{x'_\mu}\phi'^i(x')) - \int d^m x \,\mathcal{L}(\phi^i(x), \partial_{x_\mu} \phi^i(x))
$$
$$
= \int d^m x\, (1 + \partial_\mu (\omega_a \partial_{\omega_a} x_\mu)) \mathcal{L}(\phi^i + F^i_a \omega_a, (\partial_{\mu \nu} - \partial_\mu (\omega_a \partial_{\omega_a} x_\nu)) \partial_\nu (\phi^i + F^i_a \omega_a)) - \int d^m x \, \mathcal{L}(\phi^i(x), \partial_\mu \phi^i(x)).
$$
I calculated this myself and got the same answer as them. Up to this point, they do not use the fact that the transformation is a symmetry transformation. Next, they say if the transformation is a symmetry, then for constant parameters $\omega_a$, the action difference $\Delta S$ vanishes. Then, the remaining terms in $\Delta S$ are proportional to $\partial^\mu \omega_a$ (which vanishes when $\omega_a$ is constant) and are given by
$$
\Delta S = -\int d^m x \, j_\mu^a(x) \partial^\mu \omega_a,\tag{p.33}
$$
where the Noether current is given by
$$
j^a_\mu = \left.\left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_\mu \phi^i)}\partial_\nu \phi^i - \mathcal{L} \delta_{\mu \nu}\right)\frac{\partial x_\nu}{\partial \omega_a}\right\vert_{\omega = 0} - \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_\mu \phi^i)} F^i_a.\tag{1.43}
$$
They then claim that since the linear variation of the action in any parameter must vanish on-shell (because the equations of motions hold classically), it follows that $\partial^\mu j_\mu^a = 0$.
I tried working this out by myself, and it seems to me like this only holds in general if the symmetry is a symmetry of the Lagrangian and does not hold in general if the symmetry is only a symmetry of the action, because in this case, we would have to add additional terms to the Noether current due to boundary terms. Is this correct, or am I missing something that allows their proof to work for symmetries of the action as well?

A&S assumes that the action has a strict$^1$ (rather than a quasi-)symmetry, and so that the bare Noether current (1.43) without improvement terms suffice.
--
$^1$ NB: It is implicitly assumed that the spacetime  region of the action flows according to the horizontal component of the symmetry transformation (1.42).


So if the symmetry is a quasi-symmetry instead of a symmetry, the Noether current without the improvement term is, in general, not classically conserved, whereas the Noether current with the improvement term is classically conserved? 2. Also, you say that "it is implicitly assumed that the spacetime region of the action flows according to the horizontal component of the symmetry transformation." Is this an assumption or is this a required part of the derivation, i.e., could you make the transformations (1.42) and not change the Jacobian, or would that be wrong? Sorry if this is pedantic.



Yes. 2. It is a simplifying assumption to ensure that improvement terms are not needed.


So without the simplifying assumption, the difference in the action terms would read: $\Delta S = \int d^m x, \mathcal{L}(\phi'^i(x'), \partial_{x'\mu}\phi'^i(x')) - \int d^m x ,\mathcal{L}(\phi^i(x), \partial{x_\mu} \phi^i(x))$, i.e., no prime on the first volume element? Also, what is the physical interpretation of making this assumption (if there is one)?

No, there is a prime on the first volume element.


Then what part of their derivation changes if they do not make this assumption? 2) Also, on the page after the Noether current derivation, they use the Noether current formula that does not include quasi-symmetry improvement terms to derive the correct energy-momentum tensor (despite the fact that translation invariance is, as far as I know, a quasi-symmetry). Did they use the wrong formula and happen to get the right result, or is what they did correct and I'm just misunderstanding something?


In response to 2), I realized that they included a vertical variation of the field in order to ensure that the total variation of the Lagrangian is zero, and thus the formula for the Noether current in the textbook is applicable. (See this post for an explanation of the vertical variation terminology.)
